# Module/Method to Optimise Memory Footprint of a NumPy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I am in the process of building a data cube which automatically downloads and stores geospatial data (mainly satellite imagery).

At the moment, for a satellite image, my workflow is as follows:

1) Download the image.

2) Open the image.

3) Optimise the image by applying a scale factor, offset and changing the data type.

4) Store the optimised array.

Step 3 is fairly manual at the moment, in the sense that I have to work out the data type, scale factor and offset that would achieve the optimisation/reduced memory footprint I'd like. My aim is to make the end file as small as possible.

**I am wondering whether there is an module/method in Python that can automatically reduce memory footprint/size of an array?**

In other words, something that takes any array and can 'minimise' it.

Comment: Perhaps [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) can help?

Comment: Thanks but I need the array in memory - I just want to optimise the data values to use less memory - i.e convert `float64` to `uint16` using scale factors and offsets.

Comment: Oops, my bad. You made that clear in your question, don't know how I missed that. Not enough coffee yet, I suppose.