# Method to automatically derive array scale and offset values

Tags: python, numpy, compression

Part of the application I am developing requires me to apply a scale  factor and offset to a value (or array) in Python to reduce its memory footprint (so that when I save to file, I ultimately make the file size as small as possible by storing uint16 instead of float, for example). This is linked to: [Module/Method to Optimise Memory Footprint of a NumPy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595013/module-method-to-optimise-memory-footprint-of-a-numpy-array)

At present, this looks like the following:

```
def get_scale_and_offset(values_range, input_value, dtype=np.uint16):

    target_max = np.iinfo(dtype).max
    target_min = np.iinfo(dtype).min
    target_range = target_max - target_min

    # Effective range of data
    input_min = min(values_range)
    input_range = max(values_range)-min(values_range)

    # Calculate scale factor
    scale_factor = input_range / target_range

    # Calculate offset to bring the minimum to target_minimum
    offset = input_min - target_min    


    print(input_value * scale_factor + offset)

get_scale_and_offset([0, 1000], 68.235)
>>> 68.22499427786678
```

As you can see, the input value is not the same as the output value once the scale factor and offset has been applied. I know this is to do with the number of decimal places/significant figures that the scale_factor has but was wondering if anyone has an alternative approach?

I know that I can straight up force the value/array to np.uint16 using `.astype(np.unit16)` but that will lose precision. I want it so that 68.235 goes in, it is scaled and offset, and 68.235 comes out.

**NOTE:** The values passed in will not always have 3 significant figures, could be more, could be less - this method should simply scale and offset value to convert them to uint16 without loss of precision.

Comment: In both this question and your previous one, you say you want to reduce the memory footprint (which I take to mean RAM) yet you talk about making the file smaller (which I take to mean disk). Could you clarify - do you mean memory or disk?

Comment: Variable names inside the function, and argument names don't match.

Comment: Firstly, apologies for incorrect var names, that's just lazy refactoring. Secondly, I am ultimately wanting to reduce the file size by storing float values as integers using scale and offset values - I suppose in essence this also reduces RAM footprint which may have been why I reference both.

Comment: If you pass in numbers in the range A..B, and spread those over 65536 integers, your maximum resolution is (B-A)/65536. So if A=0 and B=131072, any number you scale will only come back with a resolution of 2. If A=0 and B=262144, any number you scale will only come back with a resolution of 4. If A=0 and B=16, any number you scale will come back with a resolution of `0.0002441`. You can't do it losslessly. Sorry.